# Slow Wattage of Thinkpad T480 Charger

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, thinkpad

Here are the problems I have with my T480:

- The "Slow Charger" warning appears in Windows. I tested several chargers on Windows and Linux that support at least 65W, but Lenovo Vantage and Sensors both state 5V/3A for the charger.
- The battery charge slowly drains when I do something with heavy load on CPU and slowly goes up when power consumption is minimal (or the laptop is powered off)
- Whenever I connect the AC adapter, I'll receive a error message during the boot process, saying that the charger wattage is lower than expected. (All drivers and firmwares are up-to-date)
- I'd tried almost all of the other online tips... including pushing the reset button for 5s, holding the power button for more than 30s or so; nothing changed.
- Using the TBT port has the same results.
- Seems there's nothing about Thunderbolt in the Device Manager or Linux command-line.
- The laptop does not turn on with only the AC adapter if I disconnect both batteries.

The problem seems to be related to the motherboard. Since Lenovo Support isn't available in my country, I want to repair it myself. Here are some questions I'd like answered:

1. Are there any other software tips to try?
2. Is the problem related to the motherboard, and what can I do about it? Where can I find and address the problem? Is there a specific chip to check?
3. Generally speaking, I would greatly appreciate your guidance in addressing the issue and hopefully fixing it, or if possible, trying to find another way to power my laptop.

[Output of lspci, lscpu, lshw, ...etc.](https://gist.github.com/fadavi/b6da48ca8e9daba5f3889b3732a1f242)
[Original Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/sgu7v1/t480_charger_problem/)

P.S. as a minimum experience, I can solder, locate short circuits, and flash firmwares.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the external power adapter is bad. See if anybody you know has a similar one and test with that. If the laptop charges/runs fine, then it is your power adapter. If you still get that error, it could be one or two things.

- The laptop battery is bad and is resisting charge but not bad enough to be marked bad by the CMOS/BIOS/UEFI. Replace the battery. You may have to do this anyway if the power adapter went bad. The bad power adapter may cause the battery to kill itself prematurely.
- The onboard power controller on the mobo needs to be replaced. Doing that is a real pain in the butt. It can be done, but it requires lots of time and being about to source the broken part. Try the other stuff first.